# .findByIdAndRemove is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Consider the following code:

```js
app.delete('/customer/:id',(req,res) =>{
    
    var idRemove = String(req.params.id);
    console.log(idRemove);//this part is working 
    var user = new Customers(req.body);
             console.log(user)//this part is working 

            user.findByIdAndRemove({id :idRemove},(err, doc) => {
                if (!err)
                    res.status(200).send(doc);
                else {
                    res.status(500).send(err)
//showing error here telling me that user.findByIdAndRemove is not a function
                }

            })

});
```

I am receiving an error that says ".findByIdAndRemove is not a function."

How can I prevent this error?

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that `findByIdAndRemove` is not a function, which suggests that the Mongoose model might not have the method `findByIdAndRemove`. Indeed, as of Mongoose version 5.0.0 and later, `findByIdAndRemove` has been deprecated.

To fix this issue, you can use `findByIdAndDelete` instead. Modify the relevant line in your code like this:

Answer (score 1):

In mongoDB `_id` is **reserved keyword** for id of specific item in database. I believe that you should **change** `id` to `_id` in your code. For example:

```
user.findByIdAndRemove({_id :idRemove},(err, doc) =>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html

`findByIdAndRemove` is not on the prototype, I think this means they intend for you to access the model directly instead:

e.g.

```
const Example = mongoose.model('Example',
  new mongoose.Schema({
    description: String
  })
);

Example.findByIdAndRemove({}, (err, doc) => {})
```

This makes sense since it would be a little awkward to use a specific DTO instance to access/modify a different one.